# Having Trouble with my Splash Screen

Tags: android, eclipse

So I just started to set up a splash screen that would show for 5 seconds and then go to my main menu. I think I labeled something wrong in the process and now my app is force closing. I'm pretty sure its a problem with my activity and my manifest.

DragonFruitActivity.java:

```
 package com.Dragon_Fruit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class DragonFruitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                    DragonFruitActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        logoTimer.start();

        // ***BUTTON SOUND***//
        final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(
                DragonFruitActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);

        ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        playbutton.class));
            }

        });
        ImageButton settingsbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
        settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        settingsbutton.class));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Dragon Fruit Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Dragon_Fruit" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true">

        <activity android:name=".DragonFruitActivity" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".playbutton" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Dragon_Fruit.PLAYBUTTON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".settingsbutton" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Dragon_Fruit.SETTINGSBUTTON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
08-06 22:46:27.942: ERROR/dalvikvm(9896): could not disable core file generation for pid 9896, errno=1
08-06 22:46:28.271: ERROR/(5531): This file is not ASF file.
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Dragon_Fruit/com.Dragon_Fruit.DragonFruitActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2737)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2107)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at com.Dragon_Fruit.DragonFruitActivity.onCreate(DragonFruitActivity.java:44)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2701)
08-06 22:46:28.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9896):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: do you have a logcat output for the force close?

Comment: See the error log may help...

Comment: Sorry about that guys. I added it.

Answer (score 1):

In your thread, try changing:

```
 Intent DragonFruitActivityIntent = new Intent("main");
```

to:

```
 Intent DragonFruitActivityIntent = new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this, NameOfActivityToStart.class);
```

Alternatively, if you want to change the layout rather than starting a new activity, remove:

```
Intent DragonFruitActivityIntent = new Intent("main");
startActivity(DragonFruitActivityIntent);
```

and instead write:

```
DragonFruitActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Incidentally, it would be better if rather than sleeping for 5 seconds, the thread did something useful like load some data for your app - otherwise it's just slowing down access to your app for no reason.

**Edit:** Try moving all your code from onCreate() to onStart(), so it's like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        
   setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
   super.onStart()
   Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
   ... // the rest of your code here
}
```

You may be experiencing problems accessing the UI before it's fully formed.

Comment: nope no luck :( Have you checked out my manifest? Would there be a problem there?

Comment: I've looked at your manifest, and I don't think so, as the error is a null pointer exception.  If it was a manifest issue, it would likely be something else.  The only thing I see wrong with your manifest is that your `uses-permission` and `uses-sdk` tags should be above the `application` tag, not below it.  However, you're using a lot of stuff in your manifest that I've not used, so I might be missing something

Comment: hnmm ya thats never been a problem before. I'm not sure what the problem is... But thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: No problem - sorry I couldn't help more, I can't really see what the problem is.  Just remember when debugging, look at the logcat output and look for where it first lists one of your files.  Double click the statement and it will take you to the file and the line with the error.  This is generally where your problem is.  If you're stuck, post the code from the file and the logcat output, and highlight the line with the error on (e.g. add a comment next to it).  This will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

As your log cat suggests..

```
at com.Dragon_Fruit.DragonFruitActivity.onCreate(DragonFruitActivity.java:44)
```

There's some problem in your DragonFruitActivity file. On line 44 inside OnCreate callback..

I guess removing that can solve the issue of NullpointerException.