# App keeps force Closing?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having Trouble with my Splash Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970100/having-trouble-with-my-splash-screen)

Recently I tried adding a splash screen and I think I messed something up because my app keeps force closing.

DragonFruitActivity.java:

```
 package com.Dragon_Fruit;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class DragonFruitActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        }
        @Override
            public void onStart() {
        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        sleep(5000);
                        DragonFruitActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    finally {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
            logoTimer.start();

            // ***BUTTON SOUND***//
            final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(
                    DragonFruitActivity.this, R.raw.button_click);

            ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
            playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    buttonSound.start();
                    startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                            playbutton.class));
                }

            });
            ImageButton settingsbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
            settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    buttonSound.start();
                    startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                            settingsbutton.class));
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Dragon_Fruit" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true">

        <activity android:name=".DragonFruitActivity" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".playbutton" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Dragon_Fruit.PLAYBUTTON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".settingsbutton" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Dragon_Fruit.SETTINGSBUTTON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
</manifest>
```

LogCat on Force Close:

08-06 23:27:56.259: ERROR/dalvikvm(10851): could not disable core file generation for pid 10851, errno=1
08-06 23:27:56.588: ERROR/(5531): This file is not ASF file.
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Dragon_Fruit/com.Dragon_Fruit.DragonFruitActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2737)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2753)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:129)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2107)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at com.Dragon_Fruit.DragonFruitActivity.onStart(DragonFruitActivity.java:48)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2710)
08-06 23:27:56.689: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10851):     ... 11 more

Comment: Sorry?? I still need help with this. Am I not allowed to find help on forums?

Comment: Sorry I dont want to sound rude and I don't want to break the rules but why can't I post something I'm still having trouble with again if I can't find an answer to my problem?

Comment: How about you work on it for a while after getting an answer rather than posting the result of each run following a fresh compile?

Comment: Whatever floats your boat sir.

Comment: It's not my boat that's sinking.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say whether this is what's actually causing the exception, but you definitely **cannot** call `setContentView()` from a thread. All UI manipulations have to be done from the main (UI) thread.

You can use a `Handler` and its `postDelayed()` method to change the view after a specified timeout. The `Handler` class is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Answer (score 0):

The error that the logcat shows is that the android system cannot find your "playbutton" in your "splash" layout.

It looks like you are trying to define your buttons in your AndroidManifest.xml. You should be defining them in a layout, like described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html
If playbutton and settingsbutton are actual activities, I would recommend capitalizing them to match java conventions.
You should remove:

```
        <activity android:name=".playbutton" 
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.Dragon_Fruit.PLAYBUTTON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".settingsbutton" 
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.Dragon_Fruit.SETTINGSBUTTON" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The reason you have a force close at line 48 is because you try to access your playbutton before you have added it to the activity, which you do 5 later in your timer. Try moving:

```
        ImageButton playbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbuttonselected);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        playbutton.class));
            }

        });
        ImageButton settingsbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.settingsbutton);
        settingsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent(DragonFruitActivity.this,
                        settingsbutton.class));
            }

        });
```

Into your timer code, so that it comes after DragonFruitActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.main).

Finally, your last issue is that you should not modify the UI on a worker thread. See this post for more info and solutions:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html